# RMStore Receipt Verification Failure Flow

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I am using RMStore to verify receipts.  As a note, I am not using RMStore for the actual purchase portion.  The process is successfully dealing with success and failure in terms of throwing errors and not delivering content if the receipt is invalid.  I purposefully changed the bundle to force a failure as a test.  My question though is with the failure process and the confirmation Apple sends.

The issue is that while this process does detect the failure to verify and therefore does prevent the content from being sent to the user, Apple still afterwards comes back with a dialog box about the purchase being successful.  The good news is that the purchase isn't successful and the content isn't delivered, but I would prefer that this dialog box from Apple not show as it will create confusion.

Here is my implementation of the check. For now I am just testing the failure scenario before doing more within the failure block.

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator *verifyReceipt = [[RMStoreAppReceiptVerificator alloc]init];

    [verifyReceipt verifyTransaction:transaction success:^{
        [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }failure:^(NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"failure to verify: %@",error.description);
    }];
}
```

Is there a way within the failure block to halt the process at Apple that creates their success dialog or do I need to perform this check at an earlier stage?

Update:

In looking further at this, the method above  is being called by the state `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` The definition of that state per Apple is:

*"The App Store successfully processed payment. Your application should provide the content the user purchased."*

This tells me that it is likely too late to prevent the dialog.  There is an earlier state, however, I would think the receipt verification has to come after purchase but before delivery of content (otherwise there would not be a purchase to verify).  So is this just a matter of having to deal with the conflicting message or am I missing something?

Update 2: Adding some more methods per the request in comments

```
@interface IAPHelper () <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
@end

@implementation IAPHelper
{
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

    NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
    NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;
    NSDictionary *_mappingDict;
}

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers andMappings:(NSDictionary *)mappingDict
{

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers & mappings
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;
        _mappingDict = mappingDict;

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {


    // 1
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    // 2
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    if (_completionHandler)
    {
        _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
        _completionHandler = nil;
    }
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    if (_completionHandler)
    {
        _completionHandler(NO, nil);
        _completionHandler = nil;
    }
}
```

Here is the specific method that calls `completeTransaction`

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `completeTransaction`? Also, have you tried using RMStore for the purchase portion and see if you still get the dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and creating the SDK for that matter!  I have pasted additional methods in my "update 2" of the OP.  I specifically called out the method that calls completeTransaction as you requested but I also included additional methods above that in case you needed to see more.  I have not tried RMStore for purchase as prior to finding your SDK I had already adapted another for purchases.  They also had a verification process but not one that works for iOS7.

Comment: Anything further based on these additional methods?

Comment: The only thing I can tell at a quick glance you is that it doesn't look like RMStore is causing the issue. Also, you should be finishing the transaction only after the content is downloaded. Letting RMStore handle the purchase would take care of this for you, BTW.

Comment: There is no content to download.  A successful purchase allows me to unlock content already in the app.  The issue I describe above only occurs when using your receipt verification.  I assume this might be due to Apple thinking the transaction is complete since from its side, it is.  I assume I cannot do this check prior to when I am doing it in the code?

Comment: Wait. If you force a failure without receipt verification (in your code, this would be equivalent to leaving `completeTransaction` blank) the issue doesn't happen?

Comment: We would be talking about two different failure points for two different reasons.  Without receipt verification, Apple is in control and has knowledge of the failures.  With receipt verification, as I understood it, we are determining success or not afterwards.  To your question, if Apple has told me "success" and I did not honor it, the same issue would occur.  This is why I am wondering if there is a way to check receipts prior to Apple thinking everything is done and fine.

Comment: Then RMStore doesn't have anything to do with this question. I would appreciate if you could remove the tag and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

We established in the comments that this question doesn't have anything to do with RMStore.

You're not testing a real fraud scenario so it doesn't matter if Apple shows an alert.

This would involve either using a fake receipt, or sending fake calls to the Store Kit transaction observer. In neither of those cases you would get the alert.

When using a valid transaction to simulate a failure scenario you can't expect Apple to consider the transaction invalid as well. There is no API to tell Apple that a transaction is fraudulent. You can only finish a transaction, or not.

Comment: I thought the receipt verification process fell under "RMStore" (whose files needed to be included for validation).  If there is a different tag please let me know. As for the "failure" scenario, I thought providing an incorrect bundle name/version might be a good way to force an invalid case (this is part of the validation check).  Regardless, since the test is happening in "completeTransaction" is would too late either way.  In order to not finish the trans I would have to know before hand that it is invalid.  This is why I am wondering if I can call the verifyTransaction earlier than I do?